# Consistency of likelihood importance sampling estimator

Tags: bayesian, sampling, expected-value, likelihood, importance-sampling

In a lecture recently our lecturer described a method for approximating the expectation of a function over a posterior distribution using likelihood importance sampling. That is:

$$ \mathbb{E}_{p(x|D)}[f(x)] \text{ can be approximated by } \frac{1}{\sum_{n=1}^{N}p(D|x^{(n)})}\sum_{n=1}^{N}p(D|x^{(n)})f(x^{(n)})$$

where $x^{(n)}$ are i.i.d. RV sampled from the prior $p(x)$, and $p(D|x^{(n)})$ is the likelihood of the observed data $D$.

He then claims that this estimator is biased but consistent. How can I see this? To see it is biased you usually find the expectation of the estimator and I cannot see how to do that here

$$ \mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{\sum_{n=1}^{N}p(D|x^{(n)})}\sum_{n=1}^{N}p(D|x^{(n)})f(x^{(n)})]$$
as the denominator and numerator are non-independent functions of $x$. Am I missing something and the denominator can be considered a constant and taken out of the expectation?

Any help or intuition much appreciated.

Comment: A sample from the prior need be weighted by the likelihood to become a sample from the posterior. That it is biased is due to the division by the average$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}p(D|x^{(n)})$$whose expectation is the normalising constant (or marginal likelihood) and hence whose inverse does not have as expectation the inverse of the normalising constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When considering the estimator
$$\sum_{n=1}^N p(D|x^{(n)})f(x^{(n)})\Big/\sum_{n=1}^N p(D|x^{(n)})
\qquad x^{(n)}\stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim}p(x)$$
the expectation of the numerator term is
$$N \int_\mathfrak X p(D|x)f(x)p(x)\,\text dx = N \mathbb E[f(X)|D] \times m(D)$$
where $m(D)$ is the marginal likelihood
$$m(D)= \int_\mathfrak X p(D|x)\,\text dx$$
and the expectation of the denominator term is
$$N \int_\mathfrak X p(D|x)p(x)\,\text dx = N m(D)$$
The ratio of the expectations is thus $\mathbb E[f(X)|D]$ and, since the expectation of the ratio is not the ratio of the expectations, **this estimator is biased.** Concerning consistency, it suffices to rescale numerator and denominator by $1/N$ and apply the LLN. Both converge almost surely to their respective expectation.